# How Hadoop stores emails data

Tags: email, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

i'm naive to Big Data field. I started exploring about its tools like Hadoop and got clarity about this framework and Map/Reduce framework but still have a lot of questions:
Actually i want to analyse emails and do some Email categoriation so i can organise emails into different categories but was wondering how should i store those emails into HDFS.
Should i first of all convert my emails to text file (composed of spaced-separated columns: Date, Author, Subject, Content..) or to sequence file composed of binary key-value pairs and then store the file into HDFS ?

I'm not used to work with sequence files but i read many articles about how HDFS store unstructured data into those type of file.
can someone please enlighten me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can go a lot of different ways (Hadoop doesn't care) but if you're just starting out i'd recommend storing it in a JSON object per line format. Have you taken the time to read the tutorial documentation http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Yes i did read this tutorial ! I installed and configured a cluster Hadoop using CDH5.3 . i started to explore HDFS and Hive using structured data but now i wanted to try with emails data ! Could please tell me why should i use the JSON format instead of a simple text file with columns e.g ??

Comment: Actually i started using Talend for Big Data to export my emails into a folder then retrieved those data into multiple columns and stored them into a CSV file. Is there any other method to do that?